# An almost sure version of Doob-Dynkin lemma with null sets

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space,
$X:(\Omega,\mathcal{F})\to (\Omega_2,\mathcal{F}_2)$ be a measurable function,
and $f:(\Omega,\mathcal{F})\to ( \mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ be a function.
Then [the Doob-Dynkin lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%E2%80%93Dynkin_lemma) says that $f$ is $\sigma(X)$ measurable if and only if there exists a measurable $g:(\Omega_2,\mathcal{F}_2)\to ( \mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ such that $f=g\circ X$.

My question is that whether there is an almost sure version for the lemma?

More precisely, let
$\mathbb{P}$ be a probability measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$,
$\mathcal{N}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ generated by $\mathbb{P}$-null set, and $f$ is $\sigma(X)\vee \mathcal{N}$ measurable, where $\sigma(X)\vee \mathcal{N}$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\sigma(X)$ and $\mathcal{N}$. Then can we ensure there exists a measurable $g:(\Omega_2,\mathcal{F}_2)\to ( \mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ such that $f=g\circ X$ $\mathbb{P}$-a.s.?